# Problema el factorial de un numero

Tags: php

Buenas tardes a todos estuve haciendo un programa en php que calcule el factorial de un numero entero.
Cuando quise probarlo no me ejecuta. ¿en que le erré y como puedo llegar a la solucion?.
Adjunto el código

```
<?php
  function factorial($num){
    if($num < 1){
      return $num;
    }
    else{
      return $num * factorial($num - 1);
    }
    $n = 0;
    while($n < 11){
      print(factorial($num + 1));
      $n++;
    }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Hay unos pequeños errores en tu código que impide que funcione correctamente, el primero es que las líneas donde defines la variable `$n` y el `while` deberían ir afuera de tu función, como están adentro de tu función por eso no se ejecuta nada, porque no "llamas" o ejecutas tu función.

El segundo problema es un error de concepto, pones que si `$num` es menor a 1 entonces regrese `$num`, pero eso está mal, te dejo [un artículo](http://allthematematicas.blogspot.com/2015/04/numeros-factoriales.html) como referencia. En general el factorial de los números negativos no existe y el factorial de `0` es `1`.

Ejemplo aplicando los conceptos anteriores:

```
<?php
// Función factorial
function factorial($num){
    // Regresar -1 en caso de que el número sea negativo
    if ($num < 0){
        // -1 será nuestra forma de indicar que el factorial no existe
        return -1;
    }
    
    // Regresar 1 en caso de que el número sea 0
    if($num == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    
    // Recursividad
    return $num * factorial($num - 1);
}

// Afuera de la función declaramos n
$n = 0;
while($n < 11){
    // Llamamos o ejecutamos la función para cada n
    print(factorial($n + 1)."\r\n");
    $n++;
}

?>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, funciona

Comment: Rta aceptada y recibida graciasss

Comment: Buen día @DanielEzequielPuig, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)